# Matlab guide rotate3d doens´t work as expected

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Why does `rotate3d` only work when specifying a handle to a graphics object?

```
% Wont work. Why?
axes(handles.fig1);
rotate3d on; 

% Works
rotate3d(handles.fig1,'on');
```

Also, `rotate3d on;` sometimes activate others axes/figures, but not the defined just above using axes(handler). This is odd.

Comment: it seems that you're giving figure handle to the `axes` function. try `figure(handles.fig1);` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with GUIDE (and GUIs in general) it is best to *always* specify a handle directly when using a function which is going to alter a specific graphics object. This prevents user interaction with the GUI from altering the expected behavior. The dependence on `gca` and `gcf` get very questionable in GUIs due to both user interaction and the fact that GUIDE often alters the `HandleVisibility` of the graphics objects.

In order to activate the 3D rotation you should specify either the `axes` or the `figure`

```
handles.myax = axes(handles.fig1);
rotate3d(handles.myax, 'on'); 

% OR: rotate3d(handles.fig1,'on');
```